# How can I obtain a boolean value about the existance or not of an entity in my EntityManager by giving it's primary key?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa

I'm working on a JavaEE application with EJB and JPA.

When I try to get an entity that doesn't exist in the EntityManager an exception occurs. but when I do:

```
Entity e=em.find(Entity.class,primarykey);
if(e.equals(null)){
      return "error!";
}
```

Can please someone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Object equals `null` is never true. Therefore, you should do `if(e == null){...}` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comment you have to use the `==` operator to check for `null`, because if the object you want to check is `null`, you can't use the [equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method (or any other method) on this `null` type instance.

Solution example:

```
public boolean isEntityNull(Class clazz, Object primaryKey) {
    Entity e = em.find(clazz, primaryKey);
    if (e == null) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**See also:**

- [Is null an Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894149/is-null-an-object)
- [Null check in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369226/null-check-in-java)