# Operate on all values before doing .findFirst()

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the following piece of code (the code for `TrResponse` and `TrNode` is irrelevant):

```
public TrResponse from(final TrNode b1, final TrNode b2, final TrNode b3) {
  final TrResponse resp = new TrResponse();
  Stream.of(b1, b2, b3)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .findFirst()
    .ifPresent(it -> {
      resp.m1 = it.m1;
      resp.m2 = it.m2;
      resp.m3 = it.m3;
    });
  // b1, b2 or b3 can be null
  // normalize() returns a mutated TrNode
  resp.b1 = (null != b1) ? b1.normalize() : null;
  resp.b2 = (null != b2) ? b2.normalize() : null;
  resp.b3 = (null != b3) ? b3.normalize() : null;
  return resp;
}
```

I'm trying to figure it out how to execute the `normalize` function for all of `b1`, `b2`, and `b3` (that are eventually non-`null`) within the same stream operation so I don't have to have those `null` checks later on (as I would have now). I've tried `.map(TrNode::normalize)` right before `.findFirst()`, but it only applies it, eventually, to the first found instance (if any).

Any clues?

Comment: I don't think there is a need to do this within the stream as the result of `normalize` are being assigned to different fields and there is no reason to treat them as a stream from a collection as such.

Comment: Just an aside this comment is, but is your use of [Yoda conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369226/object-null-or-null-object) related to your name being upside-down?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException ¿ʇnoqɐ ƃuᴉʞlɐʇ noʎ ǝɹɐ ʇɐɥʍ

Comment: It's like Mandarin...but worst :p

Comment: Is the initial value of `resp.b[123]` different from `null`? Or, in other words, is there a reason to use `resp.b1 = (null != b1) ? b1.normalize() : null;` instead of just `if(null != b1) resp.b1 = b1.normalize();`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findFirst` is doing exactly what it's supposed to here. It's a [short-circuiting terminal operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps).

You could write your own collector which just accepts the first element and ignores everything else. `collect` is not short-circuiting so would process every element. You could then use `map` as you were trying to do.

```
class FirstNode
{
    private TrNode node;

    public void setNode(final TrNode node)
    {
        if (this.node == null)
        {
            this.node = node;
        }
    }

    public Optional<TrNode> first()
    {
        return Optional.ofNullable(node);
    }
}

Stream.of(b1, b2, b3)
    .map(TrNode::normalize)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .collect(
        Collector.of(
            FirstNode::new,
            FirstNode::setNode,
            (node, node2) -> node
        )
    )
    .first()
    .ifPresent(it -> {
        resp.m1 = it.m1;
        resp.m2 = it.m2;
        resp.m3 = it.m3;
    });
```

But is this better or more readable than what you have at the moment? Not really. It's also worth noting that you'll be normalizing everything - is that required or desirable?

Comment: But the OP never cared if the result of `normalize` is null.

Comment: Also with this how can we assign to b1,b2,b3 the result of `normalize`?

Answer (score 1):

`b1`, `b2` and `b3` are not a collection but individual fields of an object.
How do you want to apply stream operations on?

Just replace this duplicate code :

```
resp.b1 = (null != b1) ? b1.normalize() : null;
resp.b2 = (null != b2) ? b2.normalize() : null;
resp.b3 = (null != b3) ? b3.normalize() : null;
```

by an helper method.

Personally I would provide specific methods in `TrResponse` to be able to apply the normalize methods in this way :

```
resp.setNormalizedOrNull(b1, b2, b3);
```

Where `setNormalizedOrNull` is defined as :

```
public void setNormalizedOrNull(TrNode b1, TrNode b2, TrNode b3){
    this.b1 = getNormalizedOrNull(b1);
    this.b2 = getNormalizedOrNull(b2);
    this.b3 = getNormalizedOrNull(b3);
}

// helper method :
private TrNode getNormalizedOrNull(TrNode node){
   return null != node ? node.normalize() : null;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I get it. I have indeed a helper/utility function to wrap and check for `null` values, but I'm looking for something different. Basically, I'm trying to figure it out (if possible because so far I can't find a way to do it like that) if I can chain two (sort of) terminal operations on the same stream...then I just need to assign the members/fields back to the `TrResponse` instance.

Comment: @ɐuıɥɔɐɯ It should be obvious from the definition of the word 'terminal' that you cannot perform anything after it.